# Can't create a recursive relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I need some help, I am trying to create a recursive relation using the code below, but keep getting an error

```
CREATE TABLE `Employee` (
  `SSN` int,
  `address` varchar(50),
  `salary` varchar(50),
  `sex` varchar(50),
  `birthDate` varchar(50),
  `dependantId` int,
  `supervisorId` int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SSN`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`dependantId`) REFERENCES `Dependant`(`dependantId`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`supervisorId`) REFERENCES `Employee`(`supervisorId`)
);
```

This is the error I'm getting:
#1005 - Can't create table `company recursive`.`employee` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: Referenced column such as `Dependant (dependantId)` need to be "keys". You probably need to defined an `ID` column that will be referenced by those two FKs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table needs an `ID` column to be "referenceable" by foreign key constraints. That column musst be `UNIQUE` and ideally `NOT NULL` as well. A typical solution would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
  `SSN` int,
  `address` varchar(50),
  `salary` varchar(50),
  `sex` varchar(50),
  `birthDate` varchar(50),
  id int not null unique, -- non nullable unique (acts as a key)
  dependantId int, -- nullable reference
  supervisorId int, -- nullable reference
  PRIMARY KEY (`SSN`),
  FOREIGN KEY (dependantId) REFERENCES Employee (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (supervisorId) REFERENCES Employee (id)
);
```

In this case `dependantId` and `supervisorId` can be null and become references that point to the same table `Employee`.

As a side note, typically hierarchies only include references to the supervisor and not to the dependant. In your case the latter is somewhat redundant and won't work well if a supervisor has more than one dependant.

Answer (score 0):

the reference should go to the SSN as it is the primary key

So you would get

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `Employee` (
>   `SSN` int,
>   `address` varchar(50),
>   `salary` varchar(50),
>   `sex` varchar(50),
>   `birthDate` varchar(50),
>   `dependantId` int,
>   `supervisorId` int,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`SSN`),
>   FOREIGN KEY (`dependantId`) REFERENCES `Employee`(`SSN`),
>   FOREIGN KEY (`supervisorId`) REFERENCES `Employee`(`SSN`)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (1,'adreess1','10', 'male', '2000-01-01',NULL,NULL)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (2,'adreess1','10', 'male', '2000-01-01',NULL,1)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (3,'adreess1','10', 'male', '2000-01-01',2,1)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Employee
> ```
>
> ```
> SSN | address  | salary | sex  | birthDate  | dependantId | supervisorId
> --: | :------- | :----- | :--- | :--------- | ----------: | -----------:
>   1 | adreess1 | 10     | male | 2000-01-01 |        null |         null
>   2 | adreess1 | 10     | male | 2000-01-01 |        null |            1
>   3 | adreess1 | 10     | male | 2000-01-01 |           2 |            1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=849c79dc8526e88972dfb65bcdeb09b0)*